# Report parameters to display values according to condition in ssrs reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportparameter

I have a report parameter @Filter Report and the dropdown values available in this filter are None, CustomerID, CustomerData

**CustomerID** -  If this option is selected , a text box will appear where the user must enter the  numeric value.

[image]

**CustomerData** - If selected the user will be presented with two text boxes Name and Age

[image]

if none selected then nothing will appear.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in SSRS

Comment: Why not show all the parameters and give the parameters the Null option? In your dataset (query, stored procedure) you can then check if the parameter is Null show all otherwise filter by the value.